Can a person challenge a felony charge if it never went to court?
Is it possible for a person challenge or expunge a 25 year old felony charge that comes up on a background check if no court records exist because the case was never brought to court?  What is the process to clear your name?

If we're going to keep this open..  Were you convicted of something?  Or are you looking for some sort of secret clearance that looks at charges not just convictions?  A conviction can be expunged but a charge cannot.  Is there a warrant out for you?  If there was some sort of administrative snafu that caused you not to be notified, that would be the most common outcome.

@JustinCave, you are asking good questions, but they are of the sort that make this personal and off-topic.  (and that will trigger jen to remark that it doesn't change the legal analysis...)  You saw the OP's original question, if you want to edit further please do.  (the answer to your first question is no, because you can't be convicted if the case never went to court, right?)

I would expect that there was no conviction in abstentia but then the question of expungement is out.  I would expect that some sort of warrant would have been issued based on not showing up whether the failure to receive the notification was the fault of the court or the defendant.  But given that weird stuff happened, it seems legally relevant to know exactly what weird stuff happened in the hypothetical we're considering.

Arrest records do exist and continue to exist even without conviction.  Some states may allow expungement, this may or may not affect federal databases.

"it seems legally relevant to know exactly what weird stuff happened in the hypothetical..." I agree, but then a good and thorough answer could address those sort of what-ifs, could it not?

For some types of very extensive background checks... Even expunged convictions will show up... That being said, for those very extensive background checks. The background checker shouldn't be finding out anything. They should be merely confirming things that they were already told.

It is possible to get a court order in Georgia sealing or expunging an arrest record under certain circumstances if no charges were actually brought. This denies prospective employers from accessing the records although they are still available to law enforcement officers for criminal justice purposes. The usual procedure (from the same link) is as follows:

Eligible persons arrested before July 1, 2013, may apply by contacting
the Georgia Bureau of Investigation (GBI) or their arresting agencies.
Such persons must complete a request form. The form must be completed
by the record holder, the arresting agency, and the prosecutor.
Upon approval by all parties, the prosecutor may submit the
restriction information into the Georgia Crime Information Center (G.
C. I. C.) database. When the information is uploaded to the database,
the arresting agency will be notified of the restriction. The
record-holder will also be notified of the restriction by email. A fee
of $25 is required.

There are other procedures in circumstances where this process is not available for some reason.
This is the type of case where access to records can be restricted (from the same source):

Georgia’s Record Restriction law (O. C. G. A. § 35–3–37) offers
restricted access to records of arrest if:

The person was released without prosecution

Upon referral to a prosecuting attorney, the charges against the arrested person are dismissed, and no accusation or indictment is
filed.

The person has not been convicted of the same or a similar offense under state or federal laws in the last five years

There are no other criminal charges against the person

Arrest records that can be restricted include photographs and fingerprints documented in connection to the arrest.


Persons charged with felony crimes may apply for restricted access
within four years of arrest if:

The felony charge was dismissed

The person was found “not guilty” but convicted of a misdemeanor offense

The misdemeanor was not a lesser offense included with the felony charge


Records of other court dispositions eligible for restriction include:

Cases that are not presented to the grand jury

Cases with no record on file

Cases with no further action anticipated

Dead docket cases




No
new-south-wales
There is a difference between a criminal record and a criminal history. There is also a separate driving record that contains driving offences; if these were criminal (e.g., medium or high-range drink driving), they will also be on the other records.
A criminal record is a formal record, kept by the police, of offences for which you have been convicted (see below for the definition of “conviction”). Your criminal record will only show offences where you have pleaded guilty or been found guilty following a trial. If you have been found not guilty or were charged with an offence but the matter was dismissed, it will not show up on your criminal record.
A criminal history is broader than a criminal record. It includes everything on your criminal record but also includes details of all court matters where you have been found not guilty, matters which have been dismissed, and matters which have not yet been finalised. A criminal history is often considered in sentencing or if you are making a bail application. It is also available to police and corrections officers.
Some convictions automatically become "spent" after a period of crime-free years (10 for adult convictions, 3 for convictions as a minor) and are removed from your criminal record. However, they remain on your criminal history. Sexual offences and convictions where a custodial sentence of more than 6 months was imposed cannot be spent.
A spent conviction is treated as though it never happened for most purposes except if the person applies for:

appointment or employment as "a judge, magistrate, justice of the peace, police officer, member of staff of Corrective Services NSW ..., or the Office of the Sheriff, Department of Communities and Justice, teacher or teachers aide."
clearance "under the Child Protection (Working with Children) Act 2012, the National Disability Insurance Scheme (Worker Checks) Act 2018 or a law of another State or Territory that corresponds to either of those Acts."
appointment or employment "in fire fighting or fire prevention" concerning an arson offence.

There is a procedure provided that allows removal from both the criminal history and criminal record of historic homosexual offences that are now no longer criminal. These are the only offences that are removed totally.
Background Checks
Note that while criminal records and histories are a state (or Commonwealth for Federal offences) matter, background checks are national - that is, the individual state records are consolidated so that one check provides a national result.
Also, it is generally unlawful to discriminate against a person based on their criminal background unless it is relevant to the particular employment. Prospective employers should only request a background check when they really need to know and should only consider relevant convictions. For example:

All people working with children (as employees or volunteers) must hold a current Working with Children check by a state or territory government. If an applicant has one, there is no need for a background check—if they don't, they can't hold the position.
The Department of Defence similarly handles defence clearances, so they, not the employer, need to see the criminal record. I know from personal experience that they are only interested in certain offences. An assault conviction does not prevent you from getting a security clearance, but a fraud conviction might.
Banks and insurance companies are required by law to check the backgrounds of certain employees, but they are looking for offences like fraud and larceny, not assault or murder. If they discriminate based on the latter, they are breaking the law.

Most prospective employers don't have a legal basis for requesting a background check.
Requests by foreign governments
Australian law doesn't apply to foreign governments (and vice-versa), and when they ask you questions, say on a visa application or at a border checkpoint, you have to follow their law and their definitions.
For example, the US Department of Homeland Security asks on its visa waiver form if you have ever been arrested for a drug-related offence. Notwithstanding that this question would be unlawful if asked by an Australian organisation, it's asking under US law, and the US has its own definitions of "arrest" and "drug-related" that may not correspond with Australian definitions. If you want in a) consider carefully the life choices that led you to believe visiting the USA was a good idea, and b) you play by their rules.
